# ModelingToolKit - PDESystem: Boundary conditions and Domain for arbitrary geometry

Tags: machine-learning, julia, modelingtoolkit

I am quite new to Julia so I maybe missed the proper documentation.

Is it possible to define a *PDESystem* in *ModelingToolKit* with symbolic BCs and Domain for arbitrary geometry?

For instance, if I want to solve the 2D Navier-Stokes equations with a PINN in the following period-hill shape with a curved ground:
[image]

How can I defined a no-slip boundary condition on the ground and how can I limit my y-axis to range from y/H = ground(x) to y/H=3 ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That just doesn't exist right now. The PDESystem parts are still under very active development.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I don't believe this is currently possible... however, with PINN you can do a lot of crazy things to impose boundary conditions by manually adding terms to the loss function. This often takes a bit of cleverness to think of a function to minimize which also encompasses your loss function but can be super cool.
This is possible, for instance, with the [NeuralPDE.jl package](https://github.com/SciML/NeuralPDE.jl/tree/master) for PINN. When you discretize by calling `PhysicsInformedNN(chains, strategy)`, you can add an additional function via `PhysicsInformedNN(chains, strategry, additional_loss=additional_loss)` where the function `additional_loss` takes in the inputs `additional_loss(phi, theta, p)` and returns a scalar which should be minimized during training. See, for example, this example given on the NeuralPDE.jl site: https://docs.sciml.ai/NeuralPDE/stable/tutorials/constraints/.